# How to redraw tabcontrol ribbon background color

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabcontrol, windows-forms-designer

We have created the tab-control which has tab pages. Now how can we redraw the tab-control ribbon background color as shown in the below image?

[image]

```
tabControl = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();

//The below API is not provided.
tabControl.BackColor = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: Where the code at

Comment: The color of the free tab control area is Transparent, so the Parent will shine through.

If you want to simply change the 'BackColor' you can do it easily by:

    Placing the Tab control onto, say, a Panel and then
    Changing the Panel.BackColor.
    Make it Dock=Fill the panel and you're done.

Comment: No its not working with it.If I create the panel and dock the tabcontrol in panel the tab control ribbon is not as same color of the panel.

Comment: if the Draw mode is normal the tab control backcolor will be transparent if it is ownerdrawfixed the how can be change it